# Order due on woo commerce says "Due Immediately"

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Summary: When someone places an order [if the payment is due] and at the top next to the tax invoice, it says “Tax invoice – due immediately”. I feel those words are a bit too aggressive. How can I change it to – Payment Due?

I am trying to fix he output on the pdf invoice by wpovernight. I am customizing the template. On the tax invoice for a bank payment it says due Immediately,

which is printed by `<?php do_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_document_label', $this->get_type(), $this->order ); ?>` this line.

That means the order details is from woo commerce, I tried to find the string "Due Immidiately" in woocommerce.

```
$string = WC_Order_Item_Product::get_type();
```

I saw some documentation but I couldn't do it. Any help will be appricaited .

Comment: Did you check woocommerce help?

Comment: Yeah, I did check worcommerce.